# Can XPath 1.0 do universal quantification ("for all")?

Tags: xml, xpath

Lets say I have the following XML (heavily simplified sample of my actual XML):

```
<myxml>
    <cities>
        <city>Amsterdam</city>  
        <city>London</city>
        <city>Paris</city>
    </cities>
    <hotelLocations>
        <hotelLocation>Amsterdam</hotelLocation>
        <hotelLocation>Berlin</hotelLocation>
    </hotelLocations>   
</myxml>
```

Now I would like to know if the values in the `hotelLocation` do actually exist as cities. I am trying to do that in just one XPath statement:

```
//hotelLocation=//city
```

However, this will give "true" back if one of the `hotelLocations` matches, instead **I only want it to give true if *all* of the `hotelLocations` exist in the cities entities.**

Any idea if this is possible with *one* XPath statement at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> instead I only want it to give true as all of the hotellocations exist
>   in the cities entities. Any idea if this is possible with one xpath
>   statement at all?

Yes, the following XPath expression will do what you request:

```
not(//hotelLocation[not(. = //city)])
```

**Read like this**:  There should be no `hotelLocation` elements whose string value does not exist among the `city` elements in this document.  This is logically equivalent making the requested statement:  All cities given by `hotelLocation` elements must also exist in `city` elements in this document.

Comment: Sounds interesting! Can you explain the query a bit?

Comment: Sure, I've added how to interpret the XPath to the answer.

Comment: @hek2mgl - It doesn't have to be `//city` either. It could be something more explicit like `/myxml/cities/city`.

Comment: Sure! or `/myxml/cities/city[@population > 1000000]` . XPath rocks! :) However, my knowledge is a bit rusty.